# PHP replace string with an HTML entity with reg exp

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I'm new to using regexp so I would like to know: How can I make a case-sensitive regular expression that matches and replaces the following in php:

```
#ampersand# => &#38;
#space# => &#160;
#through# => &#247;
```

Everything else like:

```
# ampersand#, #ampersand #, # ampersand #
# space#, #space #, # space #
# through#, #through #, # through #
```

should be ignored.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First, who says you need regex for this? Just use `str_replace().` Second, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Accepted answer will replace only these three values, any spaces between hash and keyword are not allowed there (these values will be skipped).

Comment: Thats what he wanted isnt it? "Everything else like: should be ignored"

Comment: oh.. my fault :) .. misunderstand.. my apologies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a function like this?

```
function convertToEntity($string) {
  $search = array("#ampersand#", "#space#", "#through#");
  $replace = array("&#38;", "&#160;", "&#247;");
  $newstring = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
  return $newstring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$source = '#ampersand #,# space#, # through #';
$result = preg_replace(array('/#\s*ampersand\s*#/i','/#\s*space\s*#/i','/#\s*through\s*#/i'),array('&#38;','&#160;','&#247;'),$source);
echo $result;
```

results:

```
&#38;,&#160;, &#247;
```